Stud finder continuously beeping in garage but not inside house
I am trying to find the studs in my garage. When I use the stud finder it continuously beeps. But when I test the walls inside the house it works properly. What is the reason and solution?
Searching online I see some folks suggesting that the wall could be charged if the sheetrock is not attached to the floor. In my garage I see a half inch gap between the sheetrock and the raised edge of the concrete floor. If that is the case is there a practical way of grounding a wall?
Also, manual says humidity level can affect operation. And this area is very humid.
Stud finder model:  Stanley IntelliLaser Pro 77-260
I extended the "adjustment feet" out (the two tiny feet that stick out of the top of the instrument, for laser functionality.) This seems to have fixed the issue but it was not consistent. And the manual does not mention such a remedy. Change of battery did not improve performance.
The stud finder showed similar beeping on a wall inside the home as well. This was the wall containing 2 feet by 2 feet AC intake and no studs.
I decided that the electronics of the stud finder is not working properly any longer. Got a new one and the problems disappeared.
The garage wall does have regular studs and sheetrock. A magnet can help find some of these studs as it detects the sheetrock nails (and lets you know to avoid those same nails while drilling.)

1 - Model # of stud finder? 2 - Is it possible you have drywall somehow glued/attached directly to concrete blocks?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  I edited the question. They suggest touching the wall would discharge it. But it has not work for me yet.

As @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact suggested, it's possible that you may not have typical stud walls in your garage.  Can you confirm you do, in fact, have stud walls?

@Milwrdfan I can detect some studs with a magnet and search for the nails. They appear at 31-33 inch gap. I am assuming the nails are on studs. My strong guess is that I do have studs. But need to check.

Could have double drywall in the garage.  Could have metal lath backing.   Or other things that confuse the finder.   Does it have a "deep scan" mode?   Some have that for thick plaster.  Just drill a few holes to help understand it or cut out a small section

It is also possible that your garage walls were sheathed inside with plywood or OSB and then drywall installed over that sheathing. This could confuse a stud finder.

@jay613  I have a hole in the sheetrock. I can see the studs.  Sheetrock is about 1/2 inch. Just regular sheetrock. Does not look extra thick. Could high humidity be the cause?

Static electricity and humidity are not factors. You have a firewall or a structural shear wall. Investigate to find out. Chances are you can see around an electrical box or other penetration.

So you can see directly that you have 1/2 inch sheet rock over 3-1/2 inch wood studs in an otherwise hollow wall with no other complications?   And the stud finder doesn't work at all, anywhere in this room, but works elsewhere?  Try a different stud finder, try the magnet method (see answer).  If you think it's humidity, try it on a less humid day or try using your stud finder in the bathroom to validate that it gets confused by humidity.

Trade your fancy electronic alleged studfinder for a rare earth (very strong) magnet. I use old hard drive magnets as I'm the sort of person that disassembles old hard drives for the magnets, but buying one is fine if you get a good strong one.
Find screws or nails with the magnet. Draw a line connecting the ones you find and you'll almost certainly have a stud there that they were driven into. Ignore ones that are way off the line of the others (sometimes people miss the studs.)

Situations this method has helped me where stud finders fail: 1) Drywall over thin wood lath over masonry.  Stud finder easily confused.  2) Double 5/8 drywall ceiling over I-joist.  The joist flanges are hard for the finder to see through over an inch of rock.   3) Drywall screwed over older walls of all kinds. No hope for a stud finder.  (With #3, no hope of attaching things securely without direct observation of the innards of the wall ... but that's another question.)
